# What does Opt. S.D. mean?

Tags: notation, terminology, sheet-music

I was looking at the [sheet music for the Star Spangled Banner arranged for the U.S. Marine Band](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tmxv7xv8y59b5gk/AACR1won84JY55sxIEHhfAYWa), and I saw that each instrument has an `Opt. S.D.` in the beginning.

[image: Opt. S.D.]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Optional Snare Drum"

What you're seeing is a cue for an optional instrument. The Star-Spangled Banner may begin with or without snare drum.

Comment: I guess it's a roll, looking at the tremolo note. Just like the U.K. National Anthem.  On those dots, it looks like a 2 beat rather than an unmeasured roll, but it's probably optional, as it says. Optional instrument, or optional beats.

Comment: @Tim Actually measured / unmeasured has nothing to do with beat length, but rather whether or not the percussionist's hands are subdividing the roll rhythmically, or non-rhythmically.

Comment: It's more likely to be a military roll at the start, just a long sustained sound.