# What does "cut. S. D." Mean in sheet music?

Tags: notation, terminology, sheet-music

What does cut. s.d. mean when written in sheet music?

Comment: If you can include an image or link to an example of where you've seen this, it might help.

Comment: My guess is it's a typo of 'cut D.S.' which would mean "skip the repeat" if someone wanted the piece to be shorter.

Comment: Leave out the snare drum, perhaps...?

Answer (score 1):

I can only imagine that the sign is like D$, (del segno) which means go to the place where $ is shown, and play from there. Sometimes it's just DS with the $ at the beginning of where to go next. A pic would help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what "cut." would be an abbreviation for but "S.D." most likely means "snare drum".

See this very similar question: [What does Opt. S.D. mean?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/38997/what-does-opt-s-d-mean?rq=1)